# Where to measure the DC voltage in RPi?

Tags: hardware, power-supply

I have got a power source for my RPi. The manufacturer claims that the output voltage is exactly 5V. However, I would like to measure whether it is true, and I would like to find out how stable it is when I connect other devices. Where it is easiest to measure the voltage with a "needle" volt-metre?

I was thinking about the 5V GPIO pins but I'm not sure if the voltage there is the same as on the input to the device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [this section](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Hardware#Power) of the eLinux pi hardware page and scroll down a few inches until you see a picture of someone holding multimeter leads.  TP1 and TP2 are stencilled clearly on the board.

Image taken from [eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/Rpi_Hardware#Power):
[image]