# How to measure Power Supply without Extra Hardware on B+ and RPi 2

Tags: hardware, power-supply

As shown in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/where-to-measure-the-dc-voltage-in-rpi), for the Raspberry Pi model B, in order to measure the voltage you just connect a multimeter to the TP1 and 2 pads. How is this done on the Raspberry Pi model B+ and 2 which are not labeled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not as conveniently this can also be done on the raspberry pi B+ and 2 by connecting the Vcc (red lead) of the multimeter to PP7 on the bottom of the board and Gnd (black lead) to PP3.

[image]

Comment: Frankly I feel it is much simpler to measure between pins 4 (5V) and 6 (ground).  Preferably by attaching jumper leads to the pins and then measuring the voltage at the end of the wires suitably spaced to prevent a short circuit.  That works on all the Pis apart from the compute module.

Comment: True, but like you said you must take precautions to not short the GPIO pins 3v and 5v together. This is a safer way for a beginner I would think.