# Raspberry pi shutting down randomly

Tags: cpu

I've been using my raspberry pi for about 3 days, and on these 3 days the Pi has stopped running 2 times. It just shuts down. I'm using it as a server and it gets kind off warm when I'm using it. (I'm using it 24/7.)

I'm using a trancend 8gb SDHC micro card. And for the power im using a regular Samsung s5 charger. And I'm using a hdmi cable for the monitor and a ethernet cable for internet.

Thats basically it, does anyone has any idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: This will be hard answer. Do you have anything to narrow it down? Anything unusual happening befor shutdown? Had a look in the log files?

Comment: No i have my monitor off, so i cant see the screen, i just hear the external the harddrive and Pi's sound disapearing, and then its shut off

Comment: But it's still worth to check the logs. What's your OS (rasbian?)?

Comment: yea its rasbian, the reccomended one. i have shut down my Pi at the moment because of the heat, can i still see the logs of when it happend, if i turn it back on?

Comment: Yes, you should find those logs (unless /var is not mounted in RAM). Have a look to /var/log/*

Comment: You're not using "a regular Samsung s5 charger".  The Samsung s5 comes with a USB 3.0 charger.  Are you certain you're supplying enough power for the PI and all peripherals? How hot is hot? I know people don't like their electronics warm, but the PI can actually withstand a lot of heat.  It might be worthwhile to add a cron entry that records the temp every 5 minutes

Answer (score 3):

This is most always a case of either a bad power supply or software that is too "heavy" on the pi.

### Hardware

Some times adapters output a different voltage/current then the label says they do.  If you have a multimeter you can [check](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31762/how-to-measure-power-supply-without-extra-hardware-on-b-and-rpi-2?lq=1) to see the current and voltage output of your charger. In order for you Pi to run properly in an idle state for most boards it [needs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) at least 700 mA and between 4.75 V (absolute minimum) and 5.25 volts. Depending on peripherals such as, high current Wifi adapters, wireless keyboard adapters, and external hard drives, you will need more current input.

### Software

The issue could also be a problem with the software overloading the Pi. You could write a simple script to monitor the cpu usage to check this. Sort of something like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/visualising-core-load-on-the-pi-2/) or [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/get-cpu-and-gpu-usage-on-raspberry-pi).  If you are running your pi headless as a server if you have not already done so I suggest you run `sudo raspi-config` and split the ram to give the most to the cpu since you are not using the gpu.

Comment: Hello thanks for replying, how do i split the ram when i typed `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: nevermind i found it, but how much memory should i use on the cpu? its says 16/32/64/128/256

Comment: Since I understand you are not using the GUI I would give it the full 256!

Comment: I saw a post about ram split with this command `sudo rpi-update 240/16` is this the same thing, just a different way to do it?

Comment: I  am unaware of that command. However, I would suspect that all that does is update your system before changing ram allocation to 240 for CPU and 16 for GPU. Could you post the link? I can't find anything like that.

Comment: i found this in this thread [link]http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/how-can-i-change-the-ram-split and another thing do i only need to reboot after chaning in rasp-config?

Comment: Ok...yes I was just about to post that. Yes regardless you have to reboot for the changes to have affect because it is a core system setting.

Comment: Okey, so its not any different from using the method i linked? anyway thanks for helping me with this issue :)

Comment: As, far as changing the RAM allocation, no, its not any different.